# Save variable in .awk file after completion for next time it runs

Tags: xml, awk

So, I have a .awk file that will split one order file into many order files. The file name goes from orders.xml (main file containing say, 100 orders) into files that increment like order-1.xml, order-2.xml, order-3.xml etc.

When the .awk file is finished splitting the files, assume the last file is order-100.xml, how can I save that number for next time, so when the .awk file runs again, it begins from 101? so it will go order-101.xml, order-102.xml etc.

This is the current code I have but I can't figure out how to do it.

The variable being incremented is the 'count' variable, which applies the file name

script.awk

```
/<Order/ {
        rfile="order-" count ".xml"
        print $0 > rfile
        getline
        while ($0 !~ "<\/Order>" ) {
                print > rfile
                getline
        }
        print $0 > rfile
        close(rfile)
        count++
}
```

So, to sum it up, say the script finishes on order-65.xml, the next time it runs, it should start from 66.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't appear to be an appropriate use of `getline`, and you're using it incorrectly, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you do what you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested since you haven't provided sample input/output to test against) is what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
outdir='/some/dir'    # set this to whatever directory path you want to create the files in.
lastNr=$(printf '%s\n' "$outdir"/order-*.xml | sed 's/.*-\([^.]*\).*/\1/' | sort -n | tail -1)

awk -v count="$lastNr" -v outdir="$outdir" '
    /<Order/ {
        close(rfile)
        rfile = outdir "/order-" (++count) ".xml"
    }
    { print > rfile }
' "${@:--}"
```

You asked how to save the value of `count` between calls to the awk script but you're already saving that as part of the names of the files you're creating so the above shell script just reads that value back into `lastNr` before calling awk. I gave it a different name from `count` partially to make it clear what's a shell variable (`lastNr`) vs an awk variable (`count`).

Save that in a file called something like `splitOrders`, make it executable, and then execute it as `./splitOrders orders.xml`

Note that `splitOrders` is a **shell** script, not an awk script. Internally it calls awk to interpret an awk script but it calls other commands (printf, sed, sort, and tail) too. Not also that a shell script is just one implementation of a command in Unix and you just name commands based on what they DO, not the language they're written in, so you don't give it a `.sh` or any other kind of language/tool-dependent suffix.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown attempts, please have following code, in order to start xml file names from taking count from next to where it ended last time, create a file to keep its last time count and read it in starting of awk program each time it runs.

```
cat script.bash
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -f lastTimeCount.txt ]]
then
     varCount="1"
else
     varCount=$(cat lastTimeCount.txt)
fi

awk -v lastCount=$(varCount) '
BEGIN{ count=lastCount }
/<Order/ {
        rfile="order-" ++count ".xml"
        print > (rfile)
        getline
        while ($0 !~ "<\/Order>" ) {
                print > (rfile)
                getline
        }
        print > (rfile)
        close(rfile)
}
END{ print count > (lastTimeCount.txt) }
' Input_file
```

Comment: Two questions (sorry), I am new to this whole .awk programming. Can one line terminal awk scripts be run in a .awk file or is it completely different? and question 2, I don't want to hard code the '100', I want to make sure that whatever the count lands on the LAST time the script was ran, it begins on next time. So, if count ended on 56 last time, next time, it will begin on 57. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: @DonnieBerry, yes code in `.awk` file is little different on running wise when we run it a direct awk code, in .awk script we need to run it by `awk -f script.awk file` format. Coming to your remembering the file name, let me fix it and get back here.

Comment: @DonnieBerry, I have edited code now, this will create a output file named `lastTimeCount.txt` from where it will pick it up and start next to that count. Kindly do check it once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Getting a syntax error. The context is: awk -v >>>  lastCount= <<< $(cat lastTimeCount.txt) '

Comment: @DonnieBerry, I just tested this is working fine for me. Create first time dummy file `touch lastTimeCount.txt` and then try running command once?

Comment: Tried that, so weird! Same error. Error in full is: awk: syntax error at source line 7 source file split-xml.awk 
 context is
 awk -v >>>  lastCount= <<< $(cat lastTimeCount.txt)' 
awk: bailing out at source line 7 source file split-xml.awk

Comment: @DonnieBerry, oh ok, you are on Sun OS, then try changing `awk` TO `nawk` and run same code, that should fly IMHO, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry, should have said, I am on a Mac but they use UNIX so I thought the awk command would work as smoothly? Anyway, changing the terminal command to nawk didnt work, it says command isn't found

Comment: @DonnieBerry, sorry seeing your error I saw bailing out error so thought its mac O.S, let me do a tweak to code in a min.

Comment: @DonnieBerry, I have edited the code now. What it does is: if output file name `lastTimeCount.txt` is NOT present(which has count where it ended last time) then it will set count to `1` once 1st run is done then it should pick it from last time where it ended in next run of this script. NOTE: I have created script named `script.bash` which has all this code in it, make sure to give proper permissions to it and then try running it, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Still having some errors.. Can I ask though, I thought the terminals on mac and linux were more or less the same? Even running this simple .awk script: testvar=$(cat test.txt)
echo $testvar, gives me errors, it says there is a syntax error on the fullstop on the word 'test.txt', I don't see a syntax error but people on linux say it works, is there a reason for that?

Comment: @DonnieBerry, this code should work on Linux, I don't have Mac OS with me, but most of the awk codes work there, please give me error in comments here what you are seeing in code tags `like this`.

Comment: `testvar=$(cat test.txt) echo $testvar` is a shell script, not an awk script. awk is not shell. Ravinder didn't just post an awk script, he posted a shell script which, among other things, calls awk to execute an awk script. You are mixing up awk and shell and THAT is what's causing your problems, not MacOS vs Linux.

Comment: So, to be clear - you're getting those syntax errors because you're executing `awk -f scriptfile` but `scriptfile` doesn't contain an awk script, it contains a shell script. That's like running a C compiler on a file containing Fortran code - yes it will give you syntax errors.

Comment: Syntax error in the awk script `(lastTimeCount.txt)` --> `("lastTimeCount.txt")`

Comment: @DonnieBerry, Please try suggestion made by @ rowboat in previous comment and let us know if that helps you, thank you.