# 3 syntax errors in .awk script at dollar signs and full stops, can't figure out what is wrong

Tags: macos, awk, macos-big-sur

Trying to implement a simple awk script to separate one big order file into individual orders, but I am getting syntax errors on the starting lines.

I have a lastTimeCount.txt file which only holds a number of orders which is used for file naming purposes, but I am getting the following errors in my terminal:

[image: Terminal Log]

Here is my code for the script

```
awk -v lastCount=$(cat lastTimeCount.txt) '
BEGIN{ count=lastCount }
/<Order/ {
        rfile="order-" ++count ".xml"
        print > (rfile)
        getline
        while ($0 !~ "<\/Order>" ) {
                print > (rfile)
                getline
        }
        print > (rfile)
        close(rfile)
}
END{ print count > (lastTimeCount.txt) }
' Input_file
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Please post the error messages as text. Why are you trying to run `awk -f` a file that has `awk` inside it? If it's an awk script, it has _only_ awk script, not arguments to awk.

Comment: I already told you **exactly** what you're doing wrong (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68098585/save-variable-in-awk-file-after-completion-for-next-time-it-runs#comment120362729_68098751) and how to do what you want the right way (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68099722/1745001). Please read the responses you already got before asking new questions about the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead make your script a shell script. Check your scripts with shellcheck.net

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -v lastCount="$(cat lastTimeCount.txt)" '
    BEGIN{ count=lastCount }
    /<Order/ {
            rfile="order-" ++count ".xml"
            print > (rfile)
            getline
            while ($0 !~ "<\/Order>" ) {
                    print > (rfile)
                    getline
            }
            print > (rfile)
            close(rfile)
    }
    END{ print count > (lastTimeCount.txt) }
' "$@"
```

and then:

```
sh splitxml.sh some_file
```

Comment: Shellcheck says there is no errors with your script, but I am getting the same syntax errors? Any idea why?

Comment: The errors are on line 14

Comment: Did you run `sh the_script`? __Not__ `awk -f thescript`. `The errors are on line 14` What errors? Most probably your script is invalid - fix it.

Comment: My exact command is: sh run.sh orders.xml

Comment: awk: cmd. line:14:     END{ print count > (lastTimeCount.txt) }
awk: cmd. line:14:                                      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:14:     END{ print count > (lastTimeCount.txt) }
awk: cmd. line:14:                                            ^ syntax error

Comment: Sure - the script is invalid. There are many online tutorials for awk - research how to redirect output from inside an awk to a file.

Comment: The arrows point at lastTimeCount >>.<< .txt, and also lasTimeCount.txt) >> } <<